# write file in the same path as c# file

Tags: .net, asp.net

Is it possible to write file to the same directory where the c# code that writes this file is ?

I mean something like there is c:\projects\myProject\test.cs

and when there is writeFile operation in test.cs

there is for example new file lest say test1.txt in c:\projects\myProject\test1.txt

I'm running asp.net application.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for `Server.MapPath("~/Something.txt")`

Comment: Probably yes, what is the namespace of server class ? I cant fins it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also try `Application.StartupPath`